# djongo + mongodb, Array Data Insert Problem

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, djongo

I have a problem.
Stack: Django-Rest-Framework + Djongo + Mongodb.
Problem: Insert error array data

```
//models.py

from django.db import models
from djongo import models as djongoModels

class House(models.Model):
    house_id = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Users(models.Model):
    _id = djongoModels.ObjectIdField()
    email = djongoModels.CharField(max_length=256)
    name = djongoModels.CharField(max_length=256)
    house = djongoModels.ArrayField(
        model_container=House
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "drf_users"
```

```
//serializers.py
from .models import Users, Houses
from rest_framework import serializers

class InsertUserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    house = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('email', 'name', 'house')
```

```
//views.py
from .models import Users
from .serializers import InsertUserSerializers

class UsersViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InsertUserSerializers
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

```
//request.http
POST http://<domain>/drf/house/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "email": "test6@stay.co.kr",
    "name": "test6",
    "house": ["SEOU-2023-1023-0002","GYOU-2023-1022-0001"]
}
```

```
//pip freeze
asgiref==3.5.2
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
certifi==2022.9.24
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
cryptography==38.0.1
Deprecated==1.2.13
Django==4.1
django-cors-headers==3.13.0
django-filter==22.1
django-oauth-toolkit==2.1.0
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-rest-framework-mongoengine==3.4.1
djangorestframework==3.13.1
djongo==1.3.6
dnspython==2.2.1
idna==3.4
jwcrypto==1.4.2
mongoengine==0.24.2
oauthlib==3.2.1
Pillow==9.2.0
pycparser==2.21
pymongo==3.12.3
pytz==2022.2.1
requests==2.28.1
sqlparse==0.2.4
urllib3==1.26.12
wrapt==1.14.1
```

I want a final db values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCkdp.png)

Is this serializers problem? Or Djongo problem.
If remove a serializers house array field, there is no error.
What's wrong with my source code. Please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**[Self Solved]**
It's problem with between a model and a value.

```
//ArrayField: Only available {key:value} 
//models.py
class House(models.Model):
    house_id = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Users(models.Model):
    ...
    house = djongoModels.ArrayField(
        model_container=House
    )

//request value
"house": [{"house_id":"SEOU-2023-1023-0002"},{"house_id":"GYOU-2023-1022-0001"}]
```

```
//JSONField or CharField: Available {value, value...} 
//models.py
class Users(models.Model):
    ...
   #house = djongoModels.CharField(max_length=256) <= exists max_length's problem  
    house = djongoModels.JSONField()

//request value
"house": ["SEOU-2023-1023-0002","GYOU-2023-1022-0001"]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).